# EF Core 7 makes required column nullable if property name matches table name

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I have the code shown below which has one Entity Framework class, with a `[Required]` string field. When I run the code, it prints the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [MyStuff] 
(
    [MyTableKey] bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [MyTableId] nvarchar(20) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_MyStuff] PRIMARY KEY ([MyTableKey])
);
```

Note that the required column is `NULL`, where I would expect `NOT NULL`. If I change the name of the property from `MyTableId` to `Name`, it changes to the expected `NOT NULL`. Likewise, if I change the table name, it also works as expected.

In other words, a property with name `FooId` in table `Foo` is nullable, even if `[Required]`. Is there a way to disable or override this behavior? We would prefer not to have to change our property/table names.

This worked as I expected (`NOT NULL`) in EF Core 5.0. It changed to `NULL` when we try to upgrade to EF Core 6.0 or EF Core 7.0.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace EfTest
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public class MyDbContext : DbContext
        {
            public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
                : base(options)
            {
            }

            public virtual DbSet<MyTable> MyStuff { get; set; }
        }

        public class MyTable
        {
            [Key]
            public long MyTableKey { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [MaxLength(20)]
            public string MyTableId { get; set; }
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>()
                .UseSqlServer("Server=localhost;Database=ef;User Id=nope;Password=nope;")
                .Options;

            using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext(options))
            {
                var sql = dbContext.Database.GenerateCreateScript();

                Console.WriteLine(sql);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with fluent api for making it required?

Comment: Good idea. Adding code to `OnModelCreating`, setting `.IsRequired()` seems to do the trick. It would still be nice if it respected the `[Required]` attribute so we did not have to retrofit all our projects.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/30937 :) I can't say "plusone" for opening an issue though so I have to pretend I'm not saying it.

Comment: @topsail I've seen this issue starting by EF 6.0 but at that time I fixed it by using fluentApi and I thought it's my problem! but after this question, it reminds me and opened the issue! What's  the problem?

Comment: No problem just saying ty for opening the issue. But its against SO policies to say that... ;) So I can't say it.